# Did anyone make an attempt to rearrange the Talmud by topics?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, talmudic-methodology

Given that many Sugiot in the Gemmorah are out of Masechet of their rational placements, and the fact that the Gemmora isn't "sacred" in its structure.

Did anyone make an attempt to rearrange the Talmud by topics, i.g. placing all Sugiot of Shabbos in Mashechet Shabbos and taking out what's not about Shabbos?

Comment: Rambam Mishneh Torah.

Comment: @Alex Answer???

Comment: @DonielF I suspect it's not quite what he's looking for.

Comment: @Alex I don't know why you and so many people misunderstood the question. Rambam wasn't rewriting Gemmorah, he wrote a totally different work.

Comment: @AlBerko https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109881/did-anyone-make-an-attempt-to-rearrange-the-talmud-by-topics#comment368827_109881

Comment: One could say Maimonides?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Kesef Nivchar: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/19582

Comment: I don't see Gemmoros here.

Answer (score 2):

This was done for Masechtot Kelim and Ohalot by [R. Gershon Henoch Leiner of Radzyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershon_Henoch_Leiner) (c. 1850) in his [Sidrei](http://hebrewbooks.org/20463) [Taharot](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/22096).

As noted on the title pages, he collected all the relevant words of Chazal (Bavli, Yerushalmi, Tosefta and various *midrashim*) and arranged them as a '*gemara*' on the *mishnayot* of those *masechtot*.

(According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershon_Henoch_Leiner) he actually composed similar volumes on the remaining *masechtot* of Seder Taharot, but the manuscripts were lost during the Holocaust.)

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. This probably would be an answer to "Did anybody try to write Gemmoros on Mishnayos that don't have one?".

Answer (score 2):

Rif compiled his work in precisely this fashion. For example, the law presented in the Talmud on Baba Bathra 3b has no place there, therefore it was added to the tractate of Megillah which discusses laws of the synagogue.