# (Early) Acharonim on Taharot?

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, commentaries, mishna, acharonim

There is no Gemara on most of Seder Taharot apart from Maseches Niddah. There are commentaries on the [Mishnayos](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=40053#p=304) there from Rambam and the Rash as well as the Rosh, Maharam of Rottenburg and Hai Gaon. These are all Rishonim, whose comments are both important and sometimes hard to understand. Apart from hagahos, I can't find any large commentaries printed on Taharot in the back of the Gemara.

Are there any commentaries specifically on Seder Taharot from (preferably early) Acharonim that aren't just commentaries on all of Mishnayos? I understand you also have Bartenura, Gra and Tosfos Yom Tov there, and there are also modern authors like the Chazon Ish. I'm thinking of something like a Maharsha-equivalent.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134488/who-wrote-a-collection-of-gemara-arranged-to-mishnayos-taharos

Comment: It's a brilliant work but sadly only on Keilim and Oholot

Comment: Guess I could just use the "Hagahot v'Chiddushim" which is like a likut of acharonim

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want traditional commentaries on the mishnah? If your goal is to understand the mishna b'pshat or b'iyun, Rambam, Kehati, Tosefet Yom Tov, all seem like great resources. If you want to understand tumah and tahara more generally, why limit yourself to the mishnah? What about Ramba or Aruch HaShulchan HeAtid?

Comment: No strong reason, just looking for anything extra seeing as the literature in this area is fairly sparse compared to another part of Shas. Rambam, traditional Mishnayos commentaries, Aruch HaShulchan are exist for almost every sugya, but those also come with many specific commentaries.

Comment: You mention Mishna but there is also Tosefta

Comment: The Gra on Taharos is a specific work, written based on notes taken by a talmid.

Comment: The Maharsha is a commentary on the Gemara, Rashi, and Tosafos. By definition it can't be similar on Taharos. He did include Taharos in his chiddushim on Aggados though.

Comment: I know there's not literally a Maharsha on Taharos, but there could be a book with a similar level of depth of explanation

Comment: The standard is Tosafos Yom Tov for Mishnayos.

Comment: It varies by masechta. The more relevant something is, the more likely it is to have commentaries. So you could find plenty on Mikvaos, not so much on Negaim, for example.

Comment: Very true. Keilim is rarely relevant and yet very difficult!

Comment: Kahati of course

Answer (score 2):

Apart from commentaries to the whole mishnah and things you mentioned in your OP, some works on taharot include:

- [Sidrei Taharot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134488/who-wrote-a-collection-of-gemara-arranged-to-mishnayos-taharos) (only keilim and ohalot are extant)
- Rav Shlomo Goren's Shaarei Taharah on mikvaot
- Mayim Tehorim of Rav Yehudah Leib Edel
- I have heard of but not seen inside a contemporary sefer called Shaarei Daat by Rav Shlomo Feldman

The Temple Institute in Jerusalem also publishes books on kodashim and taharot, maybe they have something.

There are also some good works if you want to learn about taharot and are willing to go beyond the mishnah. For example, you could learn Rambam with commentaries, or the fantastic Aruch HaShulchan HeAtid by the Baal Aruch HaShulchan.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134488/who-wrote-a-collection-of-gemara-arranged-to-mishnayos-taharos#comment447275_134489